# Predicate Logic - Equivalent Forms of Expression

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

By checking their truth tables, I understand that these propositions are all the same proposition expressed differently:

$\forall x, \neg P(x) \leftrightarrow C(x) $ (1)

$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \implies C(x)) \wedge (C(x) \implies \neg P(x))$ (2)

$\forall x, (P(x) \vee C(x)) \wedge (\neg C(x) \vee \neg P(x))$(3)

$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \wedge C(x)) \vee (\neg C(x) \wedge P(x))(4)$

I understand how (2) and (3) can be obtained from (1) but I am having trouble obtaining (4) from (1). 
What would be the laws applied to (1) to obtain (4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall x, \neg P(x) \leftrightarrow C(x) $$
Using definition of iff,
$$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \rightarrow C(x)) \land (C(x) \rightarrow \neg P(x))$$
Using definition of if
$$\forall x, ( P(x) \lor C(x)) \land (\neg C(x) \lor \neg P(x))$$
Using De Morgan's Law
$$\forall x, \neg(( P(x) \lor C(x)) \lor \neg(\neg C(x) \lor \neg P(x)))$$
$$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \land \neg C(x)) \lor (C(x) \land P(x))$$
Using $A\lor(B\land C) \rightarrow (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$
$$\forall x, ((\neg P(x) \land \neg C(x)) \lor C(x)) \land ((\neg P(x) \land \neg C(x)) \lor P(x))$$

Using $A\lor(B\land C) \rightarrow (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$
$$\forall x, ((\neg P(x) \lor C(x)) \land (\neg C(x) \lor C(x)) \land ((\neg P(x) \lor P(x)) \land (\neg C(x) \lor P(x))$$
$$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \lor C(x)) \land (\neg C(x) \lor P(x))$$
Using Demorgan's Law 
$$\forall x, \neg(\neg P(x) \lor C(x)) \lor \neg(\neg C(x) \lor P(x))$$
Using Demorgan's Law
$$\forall x, (P(x) \land \neg C(x)) \lor ( C(x) \land \neg P(x))$$
$$\forall x, (\neg P(x) \land C(x)) \lor ( \neg C(x) \land  P(x))$$

Comment: So would (4) be just the negation of  the original statement (1)?

Comment: I've compared their truth tables and discovered that they have equivalent truth table results. If one's a negation of the other, how come their truth tables are the same?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, somehow I missed the last three lines while editing. (1) is not the negation of (4). It is equivalent to (4). As shown in the proof. First-Order Logic is sound, i.e applying the regular inference rules will never lead to formulas which are the negation of the original formula, you will only arrive at different forms of the original formula. I am sure there is a smarter way to do this proof, I just did it in one go mechanically, I will try to edit the answer over time so its a smaller proof